# what is the difference between indexOps and @Indexed

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I was reading Spring Data MongoDB's doc, and I see two different approaches to create indexes: using indexOps

```
mongoTemplate.indexOps(Person.class).ensureIndex(new Index().on("name",Order.ASCENDING));
```

or through annotation `@Indexed` and other (`@CompoundIndex`, `@GeoSpatialIndexed`, `@TextIndexed`)

My question is: whats the difference between both approaches and how/when should I use one or another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches (`@Indexed` and `().ensureIndex(...)`) achieve the same goal, the only difference being that one is declarative and the other is imperative. From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.index-and-collections.index):

> the `@Indexed` annotation tells the mapping framework to call
>   createIndex(…) on that property of your document, making searches
>   faster.

And from `MongoTemplate`'s code (specifically [`DefaultIndexOperations#ensureIndex`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/DefaultIndexOperations.java#L76)):

> collection.createIndex(indexDefinition.getIndexKeys())

In general I'd prefer the annotation approach, where possible, since it's more visible on the entity level and more readable. On the other hand the programmatic approach can be used on fields that are not in the entity. For example in one project we had such hidden fields used for searching (i.e. lowercased and concatenated) that needed an index and we created them using java code.